# Проблема с кодировкой в БД (русские буквы)

Tags: java, mysql, кодировка

Я пробую развернуть Spring проект на сервисе openshift.  Я пытаюсь писать в БД в кодировке utf-8. Однако, русские буквы попадают в таблицу БД в таком виде:

```
ÑÑÐ¼ÑÑÐ¼ÑÑÐ¼
```

То есть в кодировке ISO 8859-1 (latin-1).

в URL по которому соединяется Hibernate с БД, указываю кодировку UTF-8:

```
jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/jbossews?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

в JSP указываю utf-8

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

 <form action="addMessage" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <textarea maxlength="600" name="message"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="отправить сообщение"/>
        </form>
```

базу создаю такой командой:

```
create database jbossews default character set = "UTF8" default collate = "utf8_general_ci"
```

Такой фильтр в web.xml, не приносит никаких результатов :

```
filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Изменить какие-то настройки в файле my.conf mysql не получается, поскольку изменения этого файла сбрасываются после перезапуска БД.  Вот сама БД:

```
 mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE'character%';
 Variable_name             Value                                          
 character_set_client      utf8                                           
 character_set_connection  utf8                                           
 character_set_database    latin1                                         
 character_set_filesystem  binary                                         
 character_set_results     utf8                                           
 character_set_server      latin1                                         
 character_set_system      utf8                                           
 character_sets_dir        /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/share/mysql/charsets/


SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
 Variable_name         Value             
 collation_connection  utf8_general_ci   
 collation_database    latin1_swedish_ci 
 collation_server      latin1_swedish_ci
```

Помогите решить проблему с записью в неправильной кодировке.

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, **вопрос**.

Comment: какую кодировку html-страницы определяет браузер?

Comment: '<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>'
в заголовке страницы указано utf-8, в самой БД тоже кракозябры.

Comment: @fantastic Попробуйте заменить utf8_unicode_ci на utf8_general_ci.

Comment: не помогает.
грохнул базу и пересоздал заново :

'CREATE DATABASE `jbossews` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'
в настройках hibernet :

'#db.url= .  .. . jbossews?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8'
в заголовке страницы :

contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"

Везде вроде выставил utf-8 и все равно ошибка кодировки.  
Именно в таблице в неправильной кодировке записи хранятся.

Если напрямую через phpMyAdmin сделать запись в таблице русскими буквами, то правильно отображается и в таблице и на странице. А когда  с приложение делает запись в БД, то получаются козябры.

Answer (score 1):

Если, как Вы сказали, новые записи кириллицей отображаются нормально при кодировке `UTF-8`, значит с базой все нормально. 
Старые же записи, в которых, как я понимаю, и есть Ваша проблема, отображаются некорректно, ведь они в кодировке, отличающейся от UTF-8.

Значит, все имеющиеся записи необходимо переписать в UTF-8.

Comment: Новые записи, как и старые попадают из приложения в БД в кодировке ISO-8859-1 вместо utf8.

Comment: Очень странное поведение. Попробуйте поставить в приложении (каком?) кодировку utf8.

Comment: есть один нехороший момент в том как я это все делаю, может ли он влиять на результат?
проект отлично работает на локальной базе, с таким URL :  
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8. Но я хочу разместить приложение на удаленном хостинге , где  URL DB такой:  mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/jbossews.   Я прописываю этот URL, начинаю собирать проект, создается .war файл, затем локальный томкат сыпет ошибки, что не смог соединится с БД.  И... Этот .war файл я и отправляю на хостинг. Где вроде все работает, но нет русских букв.

Answer (score 0):

Сам боролся с этим некоторое время, оказалось все очень просто:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quotesdb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

Т.е. не `characterEncoding=UTF-8`, а `characterEncoding=utf8`

И все. Ну конечно же нужно проверить саму базу данных и как она создана.